# Cannot print to HP D1360 

Tags: 11.10, printing, hp

my printer is a hp d1360 and it was working fine until I update to ubuntu 11.10.

although I can print the test page and the status of the printer is ready to print.
I cannot print anything fron firefox, document viewer, libreoffice. I downloaded the HPLIP software fron linuz-printers.org and installed, but still isn't working. only printer test page is working.

I ran the debugger and it says it could be a bug problem if somebody could help me I will appreciated. I paste the troubleshooting logs below thanks.

```
Page 1 (Scheduler not running?):

{'cups_connection_failure': False}

Page 2 (Is local server publishing?):

{'local_server_exporting_printers': False}

Page 3 (Choose printer):

{'cups_dest': <cups.Dest Deskjet-D1300-series (default)>,

 'cups_instance': None,

 'cups_queue': 'Deskjet-D1300-series',

 'cups_queue_listed': True}

Page 4 (Check printer sanity):

{'cups_device_uri_scheme': u'hp',

 'cups_printer_dict': {'device-uri': u'hp:/usb

/Deskjet_D1300_series?serial=CN69C1N31Y04ND',

                       'printer-info': u'HP Deskjet D1300 series',

                       'printer-is-shared': True,

                       'printer-location': u'HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC',

                       'printer-make-and-model': u'HP Deskjet d1300 Series, hpcups 
3.11.1',

                       'printer-state': 3,

                       'printer-state-message': u'ready to print',

                       'printer-state-reasons': [u'none'],

                       'printer-type': 8556556,

                       'printer-uri-supported': u'ipp://localhost:631/printers/Deskjet-D1300-series'},

 'cups_printer_remote': False,

 'hplip_output': (['',

                   '\x1b[01mHP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.11.10)\x1b[0m',

                   '\x1b[01mDevice Information Utility ver. 5.2\x1b[0m',

                   '',
                   'Copyright (c) 2001-9 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP',

                   'This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.',

                   'This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it',

                   'under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.',
                   '',

                   '',
                   '\x1b[01mhp:/usb/Deskjet_D1300_series?serial=CN69C1N31Y04ND\x1b[0m',

                   '',
                   '\x1b[01mDevice Parameters (dynamic data):\x1b[0m',

                   '\x1b[01m  Parameter                   

  Value(s) 
                                                 \x1b[0m',

                   '  ----------------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------',
                   '  agent1-ack                    False                                                     ',
                   '  agent1-desc                   Black cartridge                                           ',
                   '  agent1-dvc                    0                                                         ',
                   '  agent1-health                 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with my netbook. I found the following solution in the internet:

Got to the HP website and download the hplip [hplip download](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html)

When downloading HP provides you with a good installation guide.

By following the instructions you add a new printer to your system. When printing choose the new installed printer and it will hopefully work.